# Where is the lazy quoted route in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, quotes, angular2-routing

I've watched [this clarifying keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8yAdeshpcw&index=9&list=PLOETEcp3DkCq788xapkP_OU-78jhTf68j) in which **Papa Misko** presents the new routing system introduced in the RC version.

It's contained in the presentation the solution for the *"Last Lazy Loading Puzzle Piece"*, and that relies on quoting the route component name as shown in his own example:

```
{path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp}   // Non-lazy route
{path: 'simple', component: 'SimpleCmp'} // Lazy route
```

But its not working to me! The typescript compiler is complaining though.
Here is the error:

```
Argument of type '{ path: string; component: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteMetadata[]'.
  Type '{ path: string; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteMetadata'.
    Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Type'.
```

It seems that is was not implemented yet.
Does someone know what's going on and if it's really not implemented?

Comment: As far as I know it's not yet implemented in the published RC.1 version. This router will be dropped again anyway. A new router is work in progress and I suggest to wait with the migration from `router-deprecated` until it is available.

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer Dropped? How do you know that?

Comment: It was mentioned in all kind of channels, comments to issues, Gitter, ..., also from Angular2 team members since about 1-2 weeks.

Comment: Yes Gunter is right, it's not finished yet Andre. You can use your own type of lazy-loader if you're using webpack for example. `{ path: '/about', name: 'About', loader: () => require('es6-promise!./about')('About') }`. Making sure you have `es6-promise` installed in your package.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time (06/08/16) it isn't finished yet, but if you're using **webpack** you can use a combination of `es6-promise` combined with webpack's `require()` to create your own "lazy-loading".

> When the official lazy-loading comes out, you can just as easily remove this and use the upcoming standard Angular lazy-loader.

Take a look at the example here in [angular2 webpack starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L52).

```
@RouteConfig([
  // Async load a component using Webpack's require 
  // with es6-promise-loader and webpack `require`

  { 
    path: '/about', name: 'About', 
    loader: () => require('es6-promise!./about')('About') 
  }

])
```

Just make sure you have `es6-promise` installed and inside your package.json.

`npm i es6-promise --save`