# How can I lazy load routes using Webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack

I migrated our application from SystemJS to Webpack with pretty good results except that I'm unable to get lazy routes to work.

The error I keep getting is `Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: System is not defined`. The error occurs in both vendor and polyfill generated JS files.

I tried adding a custom `System` typing taken from the [Webpack starter kit](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) -

```
interface SystemJS {
  import: (path?: string) => Promise<any>;
}
declare var System: SystemJS;
```

I tried using Node's `es6-promise` package from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37703348/3665348) -

```
{ path: 'my', loadChildren: () => require('es6-promise!./my/my.module')('MyModule') }
```

Other than that, I haven't been able to find any other alternatives. Unfortunately, the official Angular 2 documentation leaves much to be desired when it comes to supporting Webpack.

I'm using the final version of Angular 2 and the router v3.

Comment: Are you using the angular-cli? There is a loader for webpack: https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular2-router-loader

Comment: I think that System.import code splitting  is supported only in webpack2. Try using require.ensure.

Comment: @mxii Don't know how i didn't find that in my research. The solution worked. Go ahead and post it as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a webpack loader from brandon roberts: https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular2-router-loader

Or you could use the `angular-cli` which has built in support.